# How to create custom "Duplicate" buttons for Adminhtml Form in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, grid

How to create custom "Duplicate" buttons for Adminhtml Form in Magento2?

I need to create a duplicate button in adminhtml form just like product edit page in admin side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside your form container add button (in the `_construct` method):

```
class Edit extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Container
{
//....
    /**
     * Initialize form
     * Add standard buttons
     * Add "Save and Continue" button
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
    //.....


        // Here we check is that model already exists
        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('id')) {
            // creating duplication url
            $duplicateUrl = $this->_urlBuilder->getUrl(
                static::URL_PATH_DUPLICATE, // path to the duplicate action, string like 'module_route/controller/action'
                [
                    // our model's id, id - is parameter from the request
                    'id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'),
                ]
            );
            $this->buttonList->add(
                'duplicate',
                [
                    'class' => 'save',
                    'label' => __('Duplicate'),
                    'onclick' => 'setLocation("' . $duplicateUrl . '")'
                ],
                12 // sort order
            );
        }
```

Add controller's action:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Some\Thing;

class Duplicate extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * Create model duplicate
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        /** @var \Vendor\Module\Model\Name $model */
        $model = $this->coreRegistry->registry('your_model_unique_identifier');
        try {
            $newModel = clone $model; // clone
            $newModel->setId(null); // remove id
            $newModel->isObjectNew(true); // set object as new
            $newModel->setData('is_active', 0); // set another data if needed
            $newModel->getResource()->save($newModel); // save new model (clone)
            // add success message and redirect to the edit form with the newly created model
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('You duplicated the model.'));
            $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['_current' => true, 'id' => $newModel->getId()]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // if something is going wrong: catch exception & redirect back
            $this->_objectManager->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->critical($e);
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
            $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['_current' => true]);
        }

        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```

Result should look like this:

[image: result]

Comment: Greate...Thank You. @ Siarhey Uchukhlebau

Comment: How to add duplicate button in Ui component way. I have seen in catalog module but it not help much. Catalog form little messy

Comment: @mrtuvn If you mean the "Save & Duplicate" action, it just redirects you to another controllers action. But it has been added almost in the same way.

Comment: @mrtuvn I will try to research it in more detail when I have free time

Comment: i found the way  use url  in $data[] of method getButtonData to define duplicate controller action

Comment: +1 from mine :) @SiarheyUchukhlebau I face one issue when I save data in multiple table. It return error : Warning: array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer in vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php on line 356 .. Can you please tell me how solve it?

Comment: @RohanHapani seems like you trying to setData with incorrect key (first argument). Review your code and check each place where the `setData` method calling. Another way: temporary change core code on the 356 line and set before that line `if (is_object($key) || is_array($key) || is_resource($key)) {
                $e = new Exception(__('Incorrect key type')); die($e->getTraceAsString());
            }` or something similar to detect the root of the problem (like on this screenshot https://i.gyazo.com/706e612c5b03eebaad77620eaa2ffa36.png ).

Comment: But, It saves data successfully. After redirect to edit page it shows error. (think)

Comment: https://codeshare.io/50NQYm LogTrace I share here. Can you please help me?

Comment: I got it. It returns from here : $this->_getSession()->setFormData($newObj); But, don't know the reason to solve.

Comment: @RohanHapani could you show full code of the `/var/www/html/ma233/app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Edit.php` ?

Comment: https://codeshare.io/5QMOPL Please check it.

Comment: @RohanHapani try to change this line `if (!empty($data)) {
   $model->setData($data);
  }` to that one: `if (!empty($data) && is_array($data)) {
   $model->setData($data);
  }` But main problem is incorrect form data saving somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks buddy !! Now, It's working :)